# Is 'synchronized' really just syntactic sugar?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I am new to multithreading, and I wrote this code which prints the numbers 1-10000 by having concurrently running threads increment and print a variable.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
package threadtest;

public class Main{

    static int i=0;
    static Object lock=new Object();

    private static class Incrementer extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run(){
            while (true){
                synchronized(lock){
                        if (i>=10000)
                            break;
                        i++;
                        System.out.println(i);
                }
            }               
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Incrementer().start();
        new Incrementer().start();
        new Incrementer().start();
        new Incrementer().start();
        new Incrementer().start();
        new Incrementer().start();
    }
}
```

This works - I wrote up a test program to check the output, and the numbers printed are exactly 1-10000 in order.

My question is this: I've heard that `synchronized` is only syntactic sugar. But I can't seem to achieve a successful result without using it. What am I missing?

Comment: It certainly isn't. Can you cite the sources where you've heard this?

Comment: @BalusC: See the accepted answer. I think the sources were simply referring to synchronized *methods* as syntactic sugar - I'm not sure if that's exactly correct or not, but at least it doesn't contradict my findings as I thought it did. @skaffman: I could have been doing it wrong without `synchronized` for all I knew :)

Comment: @incrediman `synchronized` on a method is more-or-less the same as putting the body of the method in `synchronized (this) { ... }` (or for a static method `synchronized (MyClass.class) { ... }`). (It does get represented differently in class files, but that should not usually worry you.)

Comment: BTW:Since you are likely to have Biased Locked on, (it is the default) one thread will grab the lock and the others will go to sleep. i.e. it its highly likely that all the work will be done by one thread, the remaining threads will wait for it to finish. This is not a bug, and in your case its the most efficient way to execute these threads.

Comment: @Peter: The work is not done all by one thread. In a variation on the above code, I gave each thread a name and had them output their names along with the numbers - the work was shared equally. Any idea why that would be happening?

Comment: Why not just use the "this" keyward to gain a lock rather than a new (useless) object.

Comment: @incrediman, UseBiasedLocking is off my default on Java 5.0,  Some versions of Java 6 it is on by default.

Comment: @Gnarly, using a locking Object prevents an external caller or sub-class from locking the same lock.  However, in this case, locking on "this" would be pointless as "this" is a different object in each thread.  For a static context you need a class like "Incrementer.class"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`synchronized` is by no means syntactic sugar for anything.  There is no way to work locks in Java without using the `synchronized` keyword.

Where there is "syntactic sugar" of a sort in locks in Java is that `synchronized` can apply both to blocks (as you've done it above) and to whole methods.  The following two methods are roughly equivalent in semantics:

```
synchronized void method1() {
  // ... do stuff ...
}

void method2() {
  synchronized(this) {
    // ... do stuff ...
  }
}
```

So why would you want to do the second version instead of the first?

- Synchronized method invocations are far slower than plain old method invocations, like by about an order of magnitude.  If your synchronized code isn't guaranteed to always execute (say it's in a conditional), then you probably don't want to synchronize the whole method.
- Synchronized methods hold locks for longer than synchronized blocks (because of all the method setup/tear down code).  The second method above will hold the lock for less time because the time spent setting up and tearing down the stack frame won't be locked.
- You can have much finer control over exactly what you're locking if you go with the synchronized blocks.
- *(Courtesy of [starblue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49246/starblue))* Synchronized blocks can use objects other than `this` for locking which gives you more flexible locking semantics.

Comment: With a block you can use some private object as the lock, which prevents interference from external code.

Comment: since java 1.5 you can java.util.concurrent.Lock to guard access to critical regions. This is actually faster than using synchronized in 1.5 and 1.6. So your opening statement is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your sources are just wrong. The `syncrhonized` keyword is important to use - and use properly - when writing thread-safe code. And it sounds like your own experiments bear this out.

For more on synchronization in Java:

[Java Synchronized Methods](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

[Java Locks and Synchronized Statements](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

Answer (score 1):

Actually as of Java 5 you (formally) have an alternative set of tools in java.util.concurrent. See [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/concurrency/) for more details. As detailed in the article the monitor locking model provided at Java's language level has a number of significant limitations and can be difficult to reason about when there are a complex set of interdependent objects and locking relationships making live-lock a real possibility. The java.util.concurrent library offers locking semantics which might be more familiar to programmers who've had experience in POSIX-like systems

Answer (score 1):

Of course, "synchronized" is just syntactic sugar - extremley useful syntactic sugar.

If you want sugar-free java programs, you should be writing directly in java byte code the *monitorenter*, *monitorexit*, *lock*, and *unlock* operations referenced in [VM Specifications 8.13 Locks and Synchronization](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Threads.doc.html#22500)

> There is a lock associated with every object. The Java programming
>   language does not provide a way to
>   perform separate lock and unlock
>   operations; instead, they are
>   implicitly performed by high-level
>   constructs that always arrange to pair
>   such operations correctly. (The Java
>   virtual machine, however, provides
>   separate monitorenter and monitorexit
>   instructions that implement the lock
>   and unlock operations.)
>
> The synchronized statement computes a
>   reference to an object; it then
>   attempts to perform a lock operation
>   on that object and does not proceed
>   further until the lock operation has
>   successfully completed. (A lock
>   operation may be delayed because the
>   rules about locks can prevent the main
>   memory from participating until some
>   other thread is ready to perform one
>   or more unlock operations.) After the
>   lock operation has been performed, the
>   body of the synchronized statement is
>   executed. Normally, a compiler for the
>   Java programming language ensures that
>   the lock operation implemented by a
>   monitorenter instruction executed
>   prior to the execution of the body of
>   the synchronized statement is matched
>   by an unlock operation implemented by
>   a monitorexit instruction whenever the
>   synchronized statement completes,
>   whether completion is normal or
>   abrupt.
>
> A synchronized method automatically
>   performs a lock operation when it is
>   invoked; its body is not executed
>   until the lock operation has
>   successfully completed. If the method
>   is an instance method, it locks the
>   lock associated with the instance for
>   which it was invoked (that is, the
>   object that will be known as this
>   during execution of the method's
>   body). If the method is static, it
>   locks the lock associated with the
>   Class object that represents the class
>   in which the method is defined. If
>   execution of the method's body is ever
>   completed, either normally or
>   abruptly, an unlock operation is
>   automatically performed on that same
>   lock.
>
> Best practice is that if a variable is
>   ever to be assigned by one thread and
>   used or assigned by another, then all
>   accesses to that variable should be
>   enclosed in synchronized methods or
>   synchronized statements.
>
> Although a compiler for the Java
>   programming language normally
>   guarantees structured use of locks
>   (see Section 7.14, "Synchronization"),
>   there is no assurance that all code
>   submitted to the Java virtual machine
>   will obey this property.
>   Implementations of the Java virtual
>   machine are permitted but not required
>   to enforce both of the following two
>   rules guaranteeing structured locking.
>
> Let T be a thread and L be a lock.
>   Then:
>
> 1. The number of lock operations performed by T on L during a method
>      invocation must equal the number of
>      unlock operations performed by T on L
>      during the method invocation whether
>      the method invocation completes
>      normally or abruptly.
> 2. At no point during a method invocation may the number of unlock
>      operations performed by T on L since
>      the method invocation exceed the
>      number of lock operations performed by
>      T on L since the method invocation.
>
> In less formal terms, during a method
>   invocation every unlock operation on L
>   must match some preceding lock
>   operation on L.
>
> Note that the locking and unlocking
>   automatically performed by the Java
>   virtual machine when invoking a
>   synchronized method are considered to
>   occur during the calling method's
>   invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization is one of the most important concepts while programming in multi thread environment.
While using synchronization one has to consider the object over which synchronization takes place.
For example if a static method is to be synchronized then the synchronization must be on the class level using

```
synchronized(MyClass.class){
 //code to be executed in the static context
}
```

if the block in instance method is to be synchronized then the synchronization must be using an instance of an object which is shared between all the threads.
Most poeple go wrong with the second point as it appears in your code where the synchronization appears to be on different objects rather than a single object.